# Can't add view using scaffolding . "There was an errror running the selected generator: Unable to resolve the service for type.."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I can't create a razor view using scaffolding. My project is an ASP.NET Core Web App MVC using net6.0 . I also use VS2022.

This is the error that I get: [Scaffolding Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KopJp.png)

I tried to restart my vs but with no success.

This is my DbContext:

```cs
public class SnowballDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SnowballDbContext(DbContextOptions<SnowballDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<Habit> Habits { get; set; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<Tracker> Trackers { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Progression> Progressions { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<CalendarDay> CalendarDays { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tracker>()
                .HasKey(t => t.HabitId);
           

        }

    }
```

This is my program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataBaseConnectionString");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SnowballDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

This is my controller:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly SnowballDbContext _context;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, SnowballDbContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Habits.ToList());
        }
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have this nuget package installed

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils
```

If you do not, add it and try again

Comment: I installed the package but the outcome is the same.